# Constructive definition of tensor product is canonical

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, category-theory

I have a doubt on the definition of tensor product: I read in *Category Theory in Context* (2.3.7) that the usual construction as quotient of a free module needs not to be guessed, but can be recovered. I couldn't follow entirely the argument in the book; it was similar to the one below, so if the latter is correct they are very likely the same argument.

Let $M,N$ be $R$-modules, and  $P:=M\otimes _R N$. Let $I\subset P$ be the submodule generated by the image of the bilinear map $\phi: M\times N\to P$, and set $\pi: P\to P/I$. Then $\pi\circ \phi=0\circ \phi$, so, by the universal property of $P$, $\pi$ is the zero map, i.e. $I=P$. To recover an $R$-module structure on $I$, extend $\phi:M\times N\to I$ to the homomorphism $\bar\phi:F\to I$, where $F$ is the free $R$-module over $M\times N$; then $I\cong F/\operatorname{ker}\bar\phi$, and being $\operatorname{ker}\bar\phi$ the submodule generated by $\phi^{-1}(0)$, we get the usual constructive definition.

I have another minor question, in some way related to this one: are there any textbook or (more likely) online notes/sources that treat commutative algebra from a slightly more categorical perspective than the classical texts? By "slightly" I mean, for example, to define the tensor product or the polynomial ring using representability, or noticing where adjunctions arise: for example, for a ring map $A\to B$, $B\otimes_A -$ is adjoint to a forgetful functor; or also the localization is. So I'm not thinking of a text that uses category theory to develop new results, but that just reorganizes the old ones, wherever it is natural to do it.

I searched on some sites that sell books, but I didn't find anything; I ask here just in case that the keywords I used to search weren't effective enough, or that there are some notes which I didn't find online.

Comment: What is your question *specifically*? I find the proof you cite/give quite understandable. Maybe the only thing worth elaborating on is why $\ker \tilde\phi$ is generated by $\phi^{-1}(\{0\})$…

Comment: @JonasLinssen I just wanted to be sure about the proof elaborated from the sketch of CTC